# MYSQL query - checking if integer between range in single column string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which accepts an integer then checks it against a MYSQL table to check if the number falls between the ranges of a a records defined in the table.

The only thing is, my date ranges are defined in a single column as a string in the following format:

```
0-25
```

When making a query against this, is there any way I can parse the value in the cell to create a 'minvalue' and 'maxvalue' range?

So far I have:

```
"SELECT * FROM high_performing_instructors_reference WHERE score BETWEEN....."
```

I can edit the tables to add min and max values and use PHP explode but I wanted to see if there was a way of doing this in MYSQL first.
Thanks

Comment: Normalize. Your. Data. That's it. No other way to do this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the parts of the range column.

```
WHERE score BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(rangecol, '-', 1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(rangecol, '-', -1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man....u have saved my lots of time and my long code shorten to some lines...

Comment: Yes, just one word: Brilliant! :)